# How to select and store ContentElement UID in Flux FlexForm Configuration?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, flux, fedext

I'm currently building a TYPO3 PageTemplate with Flux and Fluidpages (both GitHub Master-Branch).
I'd like to have the possibility to select a number of ContentElements from the PageTree and store the UIDs in a variable for later rendering.

My first approach combining a Flux TreeField with a RelationField:

```
  <flux:form.sheet name="content" label="content settings">
    <flux:field.tree
      name="treetest"
      label="treetest"
      table="pages"
      parentField="pid"
      foreignLabel="title"
      multiple="true"
      minItems="0"
      maxItems="1000"
      size="8"
      expandAll="false"
    />
    <flux:field.relation
      name="relationtest"
      label="relationtest"
      table="tt_content"
      condition="AND tt_content.pid IN ({treetest})"
      multiple="true"
      size="8"
      minItems="0"
      maxItems="3"
    />
  </flux:form.sheet>
```

This sadly results in a SQL-Error because the last condition is inserted as:

```
  AND tt_content.pid IN (60|foo)
```

Where 'foo' is the title of a SysFolder with the UID 60.

Debug-Output in the frontend prints the field 'treetest' as:

```
  treetest => '60' (2 chars)
```

and the condition for the field 'relationtest' as:

```
  condition => 'AND tt_content.pid IN (60)' (26 chars)
```

Questions:

1. As a matter of fact, I'm missing something here and I'd appreciate any hint, where the crux is here?
2. Is there maybe a different solution to select a ContentElement from the PageTree?

Answer (score 1):

1) It is possible that you have either a default value, an inherited value or somehow disconnected XML which contains the other value. To be 100% sure none of these are your cause, try the same on a completely new page. The expected result of your code and selecting a page UID, is exactly the value `60` - nothing more, nothing less.

2) You may find it easier to use a `###STORAGE_PID###` marker in your `foreign_table_where` and selecting the page(s) allowed for content selection, as values in the `Behavior` tab when editing your content element or page. This value has the added benefit of being possible to allow only for certain users or usergroups, or admins only.